# Java Generics - How to read fields or invoke method on a type passed to a generic method

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, design-patterns, java-8

Convert a method to generics and is the below use case good enough to convert this to generics or there would be some long term disadvantages

**Use Case**

- Firstly, i had one publish api to publish a specific entity,wrote a specific method like `publishAccountInfo(AccountInfo accountInfo)`
- But the requirements changed and now `UserGeographyInfo` and `UserBehaviorInfo` can also be published.So I had option to write 2 new methods or convert the existing to be generic.
- Also, earlier in the `publishAccountInfo(AccountInfo accountInfo)` i was doing some logic like adding additional info from context about user id,username etc which was not part of the `AccountInfo` object which i would plan to move out to other method if i use Generic Method.

  ```
  public PubResponse publishAccountInfo(AccountInfo accountInfo){
    ConfigObj cfg=null;   //this object will have specific api url for publishing
    PubResponse response;
    AccountInfo.setUserName(context.getUser);   //This is specific to AccountInfo object logic and would be moved out.
    //using spring RestTemplate exchange method
   ResponseEntity<HashMap> result = 
           restTemplate.exchange(cfg.getAPIurl(), 
                                 HttpMethod.POST, getHttpEntity(accountInfo), HashMap.class);
   HashMap<String,String> res=result.getBody();
       response=new PubResponse(res.get("statusMsg"),accountInfo.getAccountNum()); //logging some info about what is published and what was the status of publish

   return response;
   }
  ```

If i convert to Generic am having issue at below points

```
public <T> PubResponse publishAPI(T genericType){
 ConfigObj cfg=null;  //this cannot be generic, is this fine to be inside this generic method?
 PubResponse response;

        ResponseEntity<HashMap> result = 
                restTemplate.exchange(cfg.getAPIurl(), 
                                      HttpMethod.POST, getHttpEntity(genericType), HashMap.class);
        HashMap<String,String> res=result.getBody();
            response=new PubResponse(res.get("statusMsg"),genericType.getAccountNum()); //compiler complains as there is no getAccountNum method in genericType

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class PubResponse{
private final String statusMsg;
private final String someUniqueNum;   //mostly primary key of entity saved to db and published.
}
```

> Spent good time searching for example, but could not get any similar example.Tried to go through java library code as well. [Reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html) also but could not make sense out of it :(

Comment: Reflection and generics are polar opposites to one other. One gives you compile-time safety, the other complete eschews that. If you have coded yourself into a corner by your use of generics, reflection is not the solution. The solution is to fix your design.

Comment: In this case, you are misusing generics. You are saying this method can accept anything when it cannot. `publishAPI` should take an interface called something like `Account` which has a `getAccountNum` method. You can pass any number of implementations to `publishAPI`. Alternatively, pass the account number as a second parameter.

Comment: @Michael: I was just exploring if i could use generics here so there is no repeated code.I am open to other approach.But the interface approach would not make sense because what am publishing might be totally unrelated.AccountInfo, UserGeographyInfo might not share something.Passing as 2nd param also why to pass that when i have that object itself passed as input param.Above was just 1 example there might be other fields i might log or add to response.

Comment: How can "totally unrelated" things all have a `getAccountNum` method? They are related by virtue of that fact alone. The point of *generics* is to say "I can write 1 implementation that treat these types *generically*".  If the types are totally different and need to be handled differently, you can't have 1 implementation that works *generically*, excluding ugly hacks.

Comment: my bad, i explained it incorrectly.Is there any way the current method `publishAPI(T genericType)` i can read what is inside genericType like if a UserGeographyInfo object is passed then i can log the genericType.getGeographicCountry() (i.e like userGeographyInfo.getGeographicCountry();) , or my design is totally wrong here and should not use generics?simply add a interface and pass different implementation no need of generics?

Comment: `The point of generics is to say "I can write 1 implementation that treat these types generically". If the types are totally different and need to be handled differently, you can't have 1 implementation that works generically, excluding ugly hacks` i think i got my answer here, sometimes trying to overuse fancy java features can get into trouble :) like i was about to get into

Comment: A generic type parameter for `T` with no upper or lower bound is the same as accepting Object. You have only the methods of Object available in this method. If `publishAPI` works different depending on the type of object, you should [overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) the method.

Comment: Do `AccountInfo`, `UserGeographyInfo` and `UserBehaviorInfo`  have anything in common? I mean, do they implement a common interface? Do they extend from a common base class? If not, there's nothing you can do, no matter you use generics or some magic wand

Comment: Share the PubResponse class.

Comment: @Suman Done,i got what am doing is not the right way just trying to keep the question completed with all info.

Answer (score 0):

You can take [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) as param in `publish` method and extract the exact value you need.

In my case, PubResponse has Object type.

```
public class GenericsExample {

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class AccInfo {
        String accNo;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class PersonalInfo {
        int perId;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class PubRes {
        String msg;
        Object object;
    }

    public static <T, S> PubRes publish(T t, Supplier<S> supplier) throws Exception {
        // Do your action here.
        return new PubRes("msg", supplier.get());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AccInfo accInfo = new AccInfo("accountinfo");
        PersonalInfo personalInfo = new PersonalInfo(1);

        PubRes pubRes;
        // Passing accNo for AccInfo
        pubRes = publish(accInfo, () -> accInfo.getAccNo());
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pubRes));

        // Passing perId for PersonalInfo
        pubRes = publish(personalInfo, () -> personalInfo.getPerId());
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pubRes));
    }
}
```

Or

Pass `S` directly.

```
public static <T, S> PubRes publish(T t, S s) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(t));
    return new PubRes("msg", s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AccInfo accInfo = new AccInfo("accountinfo");
    PersonalInfo personalInfo = new PersonalInfo(1);

    PubRes pubRes;
    pubRes = publish(accInfo, accInfo.getAccNo());
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pubRes));

    pubRes = publish(personalInfo, personalInfo.getPerId());
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pubRes));
}
```

Both gives you the output:

> {"msg":"msg","object":"accountinfo"}
> {"msg":"msg","object":1}

Comment: This is no point in the supplier. Just pass `S` directly.

Comment: how is the above `return new PubRes("msg", s); ` equivalent to `response=new PubResponse(res.get("statusMsg"),genericType.getAccountNum())` and i see that the only way is to pass the other value as argument. In that case it is better i write a different method or overload existing.

Comment: I know it might not be possible but why would we pass as args to method when the information we need is already in T `publish(T t, S s)` , if there are 10 things i want to capture in response then i have to pass 10 args or create a new object and pass that object

Comment: Then you need to have a generic class that is extended by all your child classes like AccInfo, etc. And within the method have all common attributes and use that common attribute to populate the PubResponse. Without that how can you refer the methods/variables present in runtime? Of course, it will fail with the reason you have mentioned in this question.